# SVG URL attribute does not provide active hyperlink (with Graphviz in Ruby on Rails 5.2.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, graphviz

My application displays a Graphviz SVG image representing a chain of subprocesses. I try to add a URL reference on each subprocess to display its details:

**business_process_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    ### Retrieved by Callback function
    # Generate graphviz
    graph = GraphViz.new( :G, :type => :digraph )
    @business_process.activities.order(:sort_code).each do |node|
      case node.node_type.code
      when 'START'
        node_color = 'blue'
      when 'END'
        node_color = 'green'
      when 'RESCUE'
        node_color = 'red'
      else
        node_color = 'black'
      end
      graph.add_node(node.code, URL: activity_path(node.id), color: node_color)
    end
    @business_process.activities.order(:sort_code).each do |node|
      if node.success_next
        graph.add_edge(node.code, node.success_next.code)
      end
      if node.failure_next
        graph.add_edge(node.code, node.failure_next.code).color = 'red'
      end
    end
    graph.output(svg: "app/assets/images/temporary_images/#{@business_process.class.name}_flow#{@business_process.id}.svg")
  end
```

The image is then displayed using an image_tag:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div align="center" class="col-md-12">
      <%= image_tag("temporary_images/#{this_object.class.name}_flow#{this_object.id}.svg") %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But even though the URL links are correctly generated in the SVG file, they are not active in the displayed page.

```
<g id="a_node1"><a xlink:href="/subprocess/12362" xlink:title="TRT_INTIALISATION">
```

**How to display the SVG image so that hyperlinks are active in the web page?**

Thanks for you help!

---

The generated SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.49.0 (20210828.1703)
 -->
<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="338pt" height="116pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 337.99 116.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 112)">
<title>G</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="transparent" points="-4,4 -4,-112 333.99,-112 333.99,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- TRT_INTIALISATION -->
<g id="node1" class="node">
<title>TRT_INTIALISATION</title>
<g id="a_node1"><a xlink:href="/subprocess/12362" xlink:title="TRT_INTIALISATION">
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="blue" cx="179.94" cy="-90" rx="100.18" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="179.94" y="-86.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">TRT_INTIALISATION</text>
</a>
</g>
</g>
<!-- TRT_SAS_SCRIPTS -->
<g id="node2" class="node">
<title>TRT_SAS_SCRIPTS</title>
<g id="a_node2"><a xlink:href="/subprocess/12349" xlink:title="TRT_SAS_SCRIPTS">
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="92.94" cy="-18" rx="92.88" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="92.94" y="-14.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">TRT_SAS_SCRIPTS</text>
</a>
</g>
</g>
<!-- TRT_INTIALISATION&#45;&gt;TRT_SAS_SCRIPTS -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge">
<title>TRT_INTIALISATION&#45;&gt;TRT_SAS_SCRIPTS</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M158.88,-72.05C147.77,-63.11 133.96,-52.01 121.86,-42.27"/>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="123.79,-39.33 113.81,-35.79 119.41,-44.78 123.79,-39.33"/>
</g>
<!-- TRT_FINISH -->
<g id="node3" class="node">
<title>TRT_FINISH</title>
<g id="a_node3"><a xlink:href="/subprocess/12363" xlink:title="TRT_FINISH">
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="green" cx="266.94" cy="-18" rx="63.09" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="266.94" y="-14.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">TRT_FINISH</text>
</a>
</g>
</g>
<!-- TRT_INTIALISATION&#45;&gt;TRT_FINISH -->
<g id="edge2" class="edge">
<title>TRT_INTIALISATION&#45;&gt;TRT_FINISH</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M201,-72.05C212.28,-62.98 226.33,-51.68 238.56,-41.84"/>
<polygon fill="red" stroke="red" points="241.08,-44.3 246.67,-35.31 236.69,-38.85 241.08,-44.3"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: the contents of image elements are not interactive, you'd need to include the SVG via an object or iframe

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works fine this way!